# How do I set launcher badges?

Tags: nintendo-badge-arcade

I figured out how to affix badges to folders.  However, the bunny said that some of the badges are special in that they are **launcher** badges.  I took that to mean that you can change the icon of certain applications to that of one of the launcher badges.  I was able to get a badge that looks a lot like the System Settings app, but I'm not sure how I can change my System Settings to that launcher badge.  Did I misunderstand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually just as simple as placing the **Launcher Badge** on your home screen.  You don't replace or attach the badge to the original launcher icon, both the icon and the badge coexist on the home screen and serve as launchers for whatever application or function they reference.  If you want to hide the original icon, you can put it in a folder but neither replaces the other.

Comment: The bunny explains it the first time you see the launcher badge machine, glad to see you have figured out by yourself.